# Visual Studio 2017 opens links in IE11. How to change that?

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, terminal, visual-studio-2017

I am using a Powershell terminal via the Whack Whack Terminal add-in.  For whatever reason, the links open in Internet Explorer 11.

Is there anyway to change it to a default browser?

I've followed the path from clicking a link and it seems like Internet Explorer is being kicked off from svchost.exe.

[image]

P.S.  The author of the extension addressed the question on the [product page Q&A](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DanielGriffen.WhackWhackTerminal#qna).

Answer (score 0):

Powershell picks up the default browser from the OS. You need to change the default browser in Windows. There are a bazillion articles for that, here is one:

[Make Chrome your default browser](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95417?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

Comment: My default browser is Firefox so it's not that.